# Framework for a C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mfc, frameworks

I want to create a **standalone** C++ desktop application which will be **close-source**, **commercial** and will **not require** the user to have the required **DLLs in the machine**.
It has, at least, to work for **Windows**. If it can be built for all platforms, that would be awesome.

This means I do not want the application to use the .NET Framework and all required DLLs must be shipped with the (only) executable the client will download.

I found and tested a dummy MFC application, it seems possible to do everything I require, but every comment I hear about MFC is that it is bad designed, about to be obsolete, bad choice, hard to use, etc etc etc.
I see lots of people recommend Qt, but I read that I can't ship the library unless I pay a commercial license, or the application has to be open-source.
wxWidgets, from what I read, seems to follow the same bad design of MFC.
However, many of the comments I read seem to be for years ago. It seems that Qt has changed its license, so something may have changed in the meanwhile.

**If you were me and had these requirements, what framework/library would you pick and why?**

Comment: Your requirements look like you need to rewrite your app in Java... All your porting problems will go away

Comment: I would dust off my old copy of Delphi 7, to be honest.

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev Porting problems isn't really the point of his question though - working on all platforms would just be a bonus. The question seems to revolve around not wanting his application to be dependent on anything being pre-installed on the machine. In this context, Java offers no benefits over C++ because he'll have to worry about deploying the JRE with his app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I see lots of people recommend Qt, but I read that I can't ship the library unless I pay a commercial license, or the application has to be open-source.

This is wrong. Qt is available under the [LGPL license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html), which means you absolutely can ship your application closed-source, as long as you provide a way for the end-user to be able to modify/update the Qt dependency. Typically this means using a shared Qt library and deploying the DLL files with your application, so that the end-user can replace the DLL files if they wanted to. However it is also possible to link statically in which case you must provide a way for your end-users to re-link it. This means that you'd have to ship compiled code (object files) with your application as a minimum. Note: I'm not a lawyer, and you should thoroughly investigate the license terms yourself before you make any decision.

> However, many of the comments I read seem to be for years ago. It seems that Qt has changed its license, so something may have changed in the meanwhile.

As far as I can tell, Qt added LGPL as one of the available licenses in version 4.5 which was released in March 2009. So yes, those comments are almost 4 years out of date.

**Note:** Apart from the specific points I've addressed, it is hard to answer your question more generally for two reasons - (1) this site considers posts asking for recommendations to be off-topic, and (2) you've said, *"if you were me and had these requirements, what framework/library would you pick and why"*, but you haven't actually said what those requirements **are** - it seems apparent that you want the library to be able to do GUIs, but what else? There are many different frameworks and libraries for C++ and they all do different things.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hints about Qt. Definitely, from what you said, Qt is not a choice to me. Regarding the requirements, I highlighted them in my question - should not depend on anything being pre-installed on the machine and I should be allowed to ship all the dependencies in my program. Also, I want my program close-source.

Comment: @Nuno Peralta: You can ship the Qt DLLs with your application also when using Qt under LGPL and your own code is closed source. I don't see a problem with that unless you want to link statically, which I wouldn't necessarily recommend for a desktop application anyway.

Comment: @NunoPeralta I think you misunderstood my answer - Qt does not depend on anything being pre-instaled, and you are allowed to deploy the dependencies with your closed-source program. Yes, you stated those requirements, but you haven't said what you want your framework to **do**.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The functionality provided by the framework isn't that important, honestly. I won't do many fancy things in the program, it's just a few web requests and calculations. I assume I could just go ahead with MFC, but I would like to know if I will be sorry of that decision in the future, since so many people seem to hate it.

Comment: @NunoPeralta I would recommend that you avoid MFC - it is out of date, awkward to use, doesn't embrace modern C++ / OOP concepts, harder to get community support for (compare - 6.5k questions on SO tagged with MFC and 27.5k tagged with Qt), and platform-specific. I've used both MFC and Qt and code which is a nightmare to write in the former, is a pleasure to write in the latter. Of course that is subjective opinion, but compare for example [this "Hello, World" sample in MFC](http://tinyurl.com/p4fh77y) (scroll down to see it) with [this Qt one](http://tinyurl.com/bcx6q8s).

Comment: @NunoPeralta Another point to be aware of is that with Qt your code (but **not** your program you deploy to your users) will depend on additional build tools for the bulk of it's features - at a minimum the `moc` tool. However this is not really a problem as it integrates nicely with Visual Studio (there is even a plugin for it) and other build systems. A second point, if you like building GUIs visually, is that Qt Designer is a lot more sophisticated than Visual Studio's MFC design tool. With MFC you have to do a lot more with hand coding, that Qt's `.ui` files can take care of for you.

Comment: @NunoPeralta: How on Earth does JBentley's answer lead you to infer "Qt is not a choice for me"??

Comment: @NunoPeralta: "just a few web requests" is almost trivial to do in Qt. Knowing nothing more about your project, I can guess that you may well regret using MFC for a simple reason: its design predates most modern design patterns prevalent in C++. Qt's API is a much more modern and idiomatic design.

Comment: Thank you all! I understand everything you say, I think, and I may agree that Qt is better and more sophisticated. The only thing that is still preventing me to go with Qt is what @JBentley says about having to ship the compiled code. I would really like to be able to just provide a single EXE to the client/user (and which is not an installer). That's the only thing that seems missing in Qt.

Comment: But still... Why not the installer? It's actually very typical with windows apps.

Comment: @AndréFratelli Because it makes no sense to me to create an installer for a very simple tool, just because of the framework I used.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see what's the problem with Qt. I agree with what [JBentley said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21169761/1329652) - it implies that it would be in fact a good choice if you're looking for a modern framework. Qt offers much more functionality than MFC.

There is no problem shipping commercial, closed-source, **statically linked** applications that use Qt. Been there, done that, and it works just fine. Single `.exe` is all you provide. I'm not a lawyer, but generally what you need to provide *on request* is a static `.lib` file generated from your code's object files, so that it can be re-linked by the end user with their own copy of Qt.

There's nothing bad about that from a commercial standpoint -- if you can't afford the cost of a commercial Qt license, the requirement to make a `.lib` file if your compiled closed-source code shouldn't be a big deal. Make it a part of your build process, so that it's not an extra burden. You don't need to distribute this `.lib` file, just provide it on request. It doesn't have to be recompiled for the requester's platform or anything like that - whatever compiler you use to compile Qt and your application is all you need.

If one is serious about it, one will ask an IP lawyer to explain the implications of the licensing terms of any software you intend to redistribute with one;s product. So it doesn't matter if it's Qt or MFC, **one goes and asks a lawyer**. It's not like somehow LGPL implies "go to a lawyer", but a possibly much more complex Microsoft license doesn't. Unless one's stance is that it's OK to ignore MS licenses, but not OK to ignore FSF licenses :/

Comment: As a counterpoint: commercial licenses may be more complicated, but the intent and the practical impact is usually clear, whereas GPL has produced a number of unfriendly surprises over the last decade or so.  I think this may be because if you're a commercial developer, you are more likely to understand the motivations and ethos behind a commercial license than you are to understand the motivations and ethos behind the GPL.

Comment: Two additional points: Firstly, I agree that anyone considering doing commercial work with a GPL or LGPL library should consult a lawyer, but would add that it needs to be a lawyer who is already familiar with the GPL.  Secondly, as an argument on the risks of working with GPL would be inappropriate here, *please* email me directly or go to my blog if you feel the need to yell at me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits

Maybe SmartWin++? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SmartWin%2B%2B

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

MFC is alive and well and will meet your requirements. I (still) use it frequently. If your app GUI is basic and does not need most of the MFC features then ATL would be a very good choice.  Both MFC and ATL can be statically linked so no DLLs need to be shipped with the app.

Comment: MFC is pretty horrible to use though, and I wouldn't recommend it to someone who is selecting their GUI library for the first time. With MFC, although it is "alive and well", you're pretty much stuck with what it already had when Microsoft started focussing on .NET, and it lacks many features that more modern GUI frameworks have. Yes, you can still do those things by coding them yourself, but it isn't easy.